# Request timed out error for font file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, iis-7

I have a site developed in Asp.Net MVC 4. While load testing the site, I found that I am getting "Request Timed out" error for a font file.

I load tested the site for 100 and after crossing 20 it starts throwing this exception for font file.

ANy ideas what could be the reason behind it ??

Comment: Is this `woff` file and you are using FireFox?

Comment: This is .EOT file and I am using IE.

Comment: We have similar but completely different problem.